# Downloading files in Ubuntu makes them "shared" in Vista

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista

If I download files using Ubuntu, and store them on my Vista partition, when I go to Vista, they all appear with the sharing icon on them. In the sharing dialog (right click > share > change permissions) it says the following (doesn't mean anything to me, but maybe it helps someone answering):

> Everyone         Co-owner
>   Scott                Owner

In Ubuntu I can access all the files from the Windows partition, whether they're shared or not, so I guess it's not really important, just a bit annoying. If I try to stop sharing any files it takes several minutes for the dialog to say it's done, even though the icon disappears off the files pretty much instantly.

If I stop sharing any folders, the files inside the folders still have the icon.

So in short, I want to do one of two things:

1. In Ubuntu, make it so any files saves to the Windows partition don't show up as "shared".
2. In Vista, make unsharing files a lot simpler/quicker!

EDIT: should also add that I already disabled everything under *Control Panel \ Network and Internet \ Network and Sharing Center*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is probably showing up as shared because you have the containing folder / a higher folder shared and it is inheriting the setting.

Sharing is about sharing files over the network and not from another operating system on the same physical system.

If you go to the top level share, just unshare it and then new items you create will not be shared.

For example, if I have - c:\share as a shared folder, anything I create in it will automatically be shared unless I manually set it not to be. This is for both folders and files.

If I unshare c:\share, any new objects will not be shared by default.

Answer (score 1):

Guess what you are looking for is (being) implemented in NTFS-3G Advanced driver. In particular, you may find this information useful: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/

Answer (score -1):

Just right-click the folder and select sharing, "in Vista" I was given an option to unshare. It worked to remove the sharing icon.