# Windows Vista - overlay icon with two people

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I had to save data from my harddisk to an external drive (with linux) and after reinstalling Windows Vista (and copying the files back) there is a strange overlay icon with two people. How do I get rid of this ?

First I thought it could be shared, but the files are not shared. The user is the owner of all those files and they are accesible to everyone.

Any ideas what Vista would like to say to me with these icons and how I get rid of them ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it means the folder is shared on the network.  Right click on the icon and go to the Sharing tab to disable sharing.

Comment: It seems sharing is disabled for these files (and directories)

Comment: okay - with http://superuser.com/questions/48126/downloading-files-in-ubuntu-makes-them-shared-in-vista this answer I was able to fix it. Thank you for your help !